# How do I implement search filter query using mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

i have few search filter user like  the following image. User can select any one two or both

[image]

these are my filters language,format and status I have written a query but its not working

```
$lang_id =2;
$format = ''; //user not selected
$status = ''; //user not selected
$request =  $collection->find(array
                            (  '$and' => array(
                                array(
                                    'language' => $lang_id ,
                                    ),
                                 array(
                                    'format' => $format,
                                    ),
                                array(
                                    'status' => $status,
                                    )

                                )
                            ));
```

I have check with or also then also its not working

if filters are empty no need to find the empty field but if it is not empty need to find the field .

Please give me a solution I am new in mongodb

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to match in results? What this is doing is looking for documents where `lang_id` is equal to `2` and both `format` and `status`  equal to an empty string. Perhaps you should start here [MongoDB Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution to above mentioned issue please try executing following code snippet

```
    $lang_id = 2;
    $format = ''; //user not selected
    $status = ''; //user not selected
    $filter=array();
    if(!empty($lang_id))
    {
      $filter['language']=$lang_id;
    }
    if(!empty($format))
    {
      $filter['format']=$format;
    }
    if(!empty($status))
    {
      $filter['status']=$status;
    }

    $request =  $collection->find($filter);
```

Comment: Thanks @Athi for your quick feedback.Also in my post I have mentioned the query to be executed in mongo shell for verifying whether documents exists in collection according to criteria.Also please provide list of sample documents which exist into your mongo collection

Comment: format and status wont be null in collection . For all documents there is value for format and status

Comment: @Athi In your post $format and $status have empty values and documents are filtered according to values of those variables which are utilized as filter criteria in mongo find query

Comment: if it is empty no need to find the empty field but if it is not empty need to find the field . I want to implement this way